# Unable to set sufficient password for phpmyadmin due to mysql error

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

While installing PHPMyAdmin, the installer tries to add a phpmyadmin user to mysql which fails with:

> mysql said: ERROR 1819 (HY000) at line 1: Your password does not satisfy the current policy

I have removed / lowered ALL mysql validate_password settings to the bare minimums and still getting an error.

I use a extremely complex password with numbers, letters, special characters, uppercase, and still fails no matter the settings.

Comment: What's the output of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'validate_password%'`?

Answer (score 1):

You can uninstall the plugin. you can run this code in root :

```
uninstall plugin validate_password;
```

.

But also you can change the plugin configuration.

You do that by logging into MySQL and running the following:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'validate_password%';
+--------------------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name                        | Value  |
+--------------------------------------+--------+
| validate_password_check_user_name    | OFF    |
| validate_password_dictionary_file    |        |
| validate_password_length             | 8      |
| validate_password_mixed_case_count   | 1      |
| validate_password_number_count       | 1      |
| validate_password_policy             | MEDIUM |
| validate_password_special_char_count | 1      |
+--------------------------------------+--------+
```

This will show you the Plugin table and the associated settings. You can manipulate any of the settings in the table by doing any of the following:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL validate_password_length = 6;

mysql> SET GLOBAL validate_password_number_count = 0;

mysql> SET GLOBAL validate_password.policy = LOW;
```

Be forewarned that I tried resetting some of the values and had little luck until I removed the plugin. In reality, I didn’t need the plugin. I use a random password generator for all my passwords.

Comment: On MySQL8, try this to remove the plugin:
UNINSTALL COMPONENT 'file://component_validate_password';